# Prepare graphics of JFileChooser before showing - otherwise flickers

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

When I set `fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(path));` and then `int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(window);` - it shows - and for a few milliseconds I can see how `JFileChooser` changes to specified directory. Not very nice.. Is there a way to prepare graphics before making it visible? Maybe `SwingWorker` could help here?

Comment: The shirt answers, the component must be created and shown within the EDT. Normally, I lazy load the file chooser, but keep a reference to it so I don't have to recreate it later

Comment: I have done exactly the same - it is created, but when I have to show it - just setting current directory and then `showOpenDialog(window)`..

Comment: Unser what OS are you running your app? Creating an instance of a JFileChooser can be sometime very time consumming under Windows as .zip files are seen as folders.

Comment: Given the same thing happens with the Windows native file chooser, I doubt there is a workable solution short of creating your own file dialog.

Comment: Windows XP... I hate Windows 8 or 10 graphics :) But I think it will happen on all Windows versions. Yes, I'm somewhere in a middle of creating my custom file chooser. Not very easy task.